# Select column that matches value in other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to extract the max temperature for the day that each data point burned in R. The first 365 columns in my data frame correspond to day of year (colnames '1', '2',...'365') and the last columns are identifiers for the data points, including day of burn (colname 'dob') which is listed as a day of the year (value = 1, 2, ...365). For each data point, I want to select the max temp value in the column that corresponds to the day of burn, e.g. if a data point burned on 227, then the max temp value in column 227 would be selected. Pretty new to coding, but this is generally how I'm thinking of it:

```
>dput(data[1:3, c(1, 225,226,227,365, 366, 374)])
    structure(list(`1` = c(645, 645, 645), `225` = c(900, 900, 900), 
    `226` = c(895, 895, 895), `227` = c(881, 881, 881), `365` = c(605, 
    605, 605), dob = c(227L, 222L, 222L), index = c("blossom_biscuit_1", 
    "blossom_biscuit_2", "blossom_biscuit_3")), row.names = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Current data structure:

```
 |    1...   | ...222... |  226 |   227...  | ...365| **dob** |      index      |
 |:---------:|:---------:|:----:|:---------:|:-----:|:-------:|:----------------|
 |     645   |    900    | 895  |  **881**  |  605  | **227** |blossom_biscuit_1|
 |     645   |  **900**  | 895  |    881    |  605  | **225** |blossom_biscuit_2|
```

Desired data structure:

```
 |  1...  | ...222... |226| 227...|...365| dob |       index      |**dob_tmmax**|
 |:------:|:---------:|:-:|:-----:|:----:|:---:|:-----------------|:-----------:|
 |  645   |     900   |895|  881  |  605 | 227 | blossom_biscuit_1|    881      |
 |  645   |     900   |895|  881  |  605 | 225 | blossom_biscuit_2|    900      |
```

Vague idea of for loop to accomplish this?

```
data %>% filter(
   for (i in data) {
                 dob = data$dob
                   x = c(data[i, dob])
          dob_tmmax <- c(data[i, x])
  return(data$dob_tmmax)  
})
```

Comment: Can you show a small example to better understand the issue along with expected output

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @akrun hopefully the edits I've made are helpful, I appreciate the feedback

Comment: @RebeccaNaekoWeber i updated the post based on your example. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the 'burn' column signifies the column index of the columns that have the max 'temp' value, an easier option is `row/column` indexing

```
df1$maxtemp <- df1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$burn)]
```

---

Based on the update, we can use `match` to get the column index from the 'dob' column

```
nm1 <- grep('\\d+', names(data), value = TRUE)
dob_tmmax <- data[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), match(data$dob, nm1))]
```